# newfloat vs tex4ht

Tags: floats, conversion, tex4ht, open-office, newfloat

When using `newfloat` to create a new type of float, `tex4ht` swallows the first line of text inside the float when it converts to `.odt` format.

In the MWE, the new float is `example`; this works the same as `table` when compiling with `pdflatex`, but `tex4ht` treats the two environments differently in the`.odt`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{newfloat}
\DeclareFloatingEnvironment{example}

\begin{document}

See example~\ref{ex:music}.

% First line will disappear in ODT
\begin{example}
Explanatory text.

More explanatory text.

\caption{Musical example}
\label{ex:music}
\end{example}

See table~\ref{table}.

% All text will appear in ODT
\begin{table}
Explanatory text.

More explanatory text.

\caption{Table}
\label{table}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

PDF output from `pdflatex file` (twice):

[image]

ODT output from `pdflatex file && mk4ht oolatex file && libreoffice file.odt`

[image]

Comment: The same thing happens if I use the `float` package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Returning to my own question, still a problem in 2020: the only solution is to put `\caption` first in any `newfloat` environment; otherwise the first line of text is swallowed.

Answer (score 1):

Did you ever try plastex?

call with

```
 plastex --theme minimal --sec-num-depth 0 --split-level 0 <filename>.tex
```

I have tried it, but I cannot get an odt file directly. I opened the html file via open office....currently. [image]

Have a look...

Comment: I haven't: does it produce better results?